# Erlang: Avoiding race condition with gen_tcp:controlling_process

Tags: erlang

I am implementing simple tcp server with the following sequence:

```
{ok, LS} = gen_tcp:listen(Port,[{active, true}, {reuseaddr, true}, {mode, list}]),
{ok, Socket} =  gen_tcp:accept(LS),
Pid = spawn_link(M, F, [Socket]),           
gen_tcp:controlling_process(Socket, Pid)
```

Using the option {active, true} might cause a race condition where a new packet arrives on the socket process before the "controlling_process" get  called , which would result in {tcp,Socket,Data} message arriving to the father proccess instead of the child.

How this could be avoided ?

Comment: It doesn't look like there could be a race condition because nothing reads anything from the socket before the `controlling_process` gets called.
So, the word _might_ in your question bothers me. Have you actually seen a race condition happen? If so, can you provide more detail?

Comment: The {active, true} flag means (if I understand it correctly) that the system actively reads packets from the socket and sends them to the controlling process message inbox as  {tcp,Socket,Data}.

Comment: I see your point. I would suggest moving the call to `gen_tcp:accept` from the process you spawned (`M:F` in your example) to avoid the condition. That way you can avoid calling `gen_tcp:controlling_process` altogether.

Comment: @Keynslug posted a good answer below while I was still typing mine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are right. In such cases you surely need `{active, false}` passed among listening socket options. Consider this snippet of code:

```
-define(TCP_OPTIONS, [binary, {active, false}, ...]).

...

start(Port) ->
    {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:listen(Port, ?TCP_OPTIONS),
    accept(Socket).

accept(ListenSocket) ->
    case gen_tcp:accept(ListenSocket) of
        {ok, Socket} ->
            Pid = spawn(fun() ->
                io:format("Connection accepted ~n", []),
                enter_loop(Socket)
            end),
            gen_tcp:controlling_process(Socket, Pid),
            Pid ! ack,
            accept(ListenSocket);
        Error ->
            exit(Error)
    end.

enter_loop(Sock) ->
    %% make sure to acknowledge owner rights transmission finished
    receive ack -> ok end,
    loop(Sock).

loop(Sock) ->
    %% set soscket options to receive messages directly into itself
    inet:setopts(Sock, [{active, once}]),
    receive
        {tcp, Socket, Data} ->
            io:format("Got packet: ~p~n", [Data]),
            ...,
            loop(Socket);
        {tcp_closed, Socket} ->
            io:format("Socket ~p closed~n", [Socket]);
        {tcp_error, Socket, Reason} ->
            io:format("Error on socket ~p reason: ~p~n", [Socket, Reason])
    end.
```

Thus you will not lost anything until `controlling_process` succeeds. It is known problem been discussed a lot over internets.
If you wish to use ready to go solution you surely need to take a look at [Ranch](https://github.com/extend/ranch) project.

Comment: Just spotted that any tail recursion into `loop` will freeze on `receive ack -> ok end`. I'll post edits to overcome this issue.

Comment: btw, what is the reason for the {active, once} instead {active, true} ?

Comment: Given simple, to prevent message process inbox flooding. There is important notion - make sure you're not using `{active, true}`. Many folks mention that. If you work with something that follows request-response model like HTTP then the `{active, once}` is what you need. Thus we provide a guarantee - if machine falls under highload VM will not go beyond predicable memory footprints. If you work with streaming large portions of data you surely need to go on with `{active, false}` and do `recv`s manually. Given such scenario this way will drastically increase performance and system bandwidth.

Answer (score 3):

If the socket is active, `inet:tcp_controlling_process` (called by `gen_tcp:controlling_process`) sets the socket to passive, then selectively receives all messages related to that socket and sends them to the new owner, effectively moving them to the new owner's message queue. Then it restores the socket to active.

So there's no race condition: they have already thought of that and fixed it in the library.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I am wondering if this is a (relatively) recent feature (given the old answers to this question and a number of similar discussions on the Internet)?

Answer (score 2):

There absolutely is a race condition. I just encountered it, today, in OTP 21.2, and that's why I'm here. A packet can arrive between the time that `accept` returns and the time that `inet:tcp_controlling_process` sets the socket to passive.

I just wanted to point out tiny simplification to @Keynslug's answer above. The socket can be set to active from a non-owning process, so the `ack` messaging and `enter_loop` are unnecessary

```erlang
-define(TCP_OPTIONS, [binary, {active, false}, ...]).

...

start(Port) ->
    {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:listen(Port, ?TCP_OPTIONS),
    accept(Socket).

accept(ListenSocket) ->
    case gen_tcp:accept(ListenSocket) of
        {ok, Socket} ->
            Pid = spawn(fun() ->
                io:format("Connection accepted ~n", []),
                loop(Socket)
            end),
            gen_tcp:controlling_process(Socket, Pid),
            inet:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]),
            accept(ListenSocket);
        Error ->
            exit(Error)
    end.

loop(Sock) ->
    %% set soscket options to receive messages directly into itself
    inet:setopts(Sock, [{active, once}]),
    receive
        {tcp, Socket, Data} ->
            io:format("Got packet: ~p~n", [Data]),
            ...,
            loop(Socket);
        {tcp_closed, Socket} ->
            io:format("Socket ~p closed~n", [Socket]);
        {tcp_error, Socket, Reason} ->
            io:format("Error on socket ~p reason: ~p~n", [Socket, Reason])
    end.
```